# Print C# TimeSpan value in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Javascript

```
 var row = "";
  jQuery.each(response.content, function (index, item) {
     row += "<tr ><td>" + item.lectureStartTime + " </td> </tr>";
       });
  $("#tbldialogfacultyclash").html(row);
```

Model Class

```
     [Key]
    [Column(Order = 9, TypeName = "time")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    [DisplayName("Lecture Start Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm tt}")]
    public TimeSpan lectureStartTime { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 10, TypeName = "time")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    [DisplayName("Lecture End Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm tt}")]
    public TimeSpan lectureEndTime { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 11)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    [DisplayName("lecture Total Duration")]
    public long lectureTotalDuration { get; set; }
```

**Image showed Database data and structure**

[image]

When I tried to Print `lectureStartTime`  Using javascript it showed me like  `[object Object]`  how to print this `C# TimeSpan Object`
I want to print like `10:00 AM` Format

Comment: You need to use the browser's debug tools and set a breakpoint inside your `jQuery.each()` loop. Have a look at the `item.lectureStartTime` object and see what keys/values it has available.

Comment: `TimeSpan` is a complex object, you need to arrange time string based from its properties to get hh:mm tt format.

Comment: @Phylogenesis  "lectureStartTime":{"Hours":8,"Minutes":0,"Seconds":0,"Milliseconds":0,"Ticks":288000000000,"Days":0,"TotalDays":0.33333333333333331,"TotalHours":8,"TotalMilliseconds":28800000,"TotalMinutes":480,"TotalSeconds":28800}

Comment: @Pravin I think you need to supply formatted string when returning JsonResult from controller, and use `DateTime` instead `TimeSpan`. This reference may help you returning JSON string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511709/json-timespan-return-object.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  Actually I started with plan string datatype but that not support me like in such condition like get rows between specific starttime and endtime for that I changed it to timespan

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  timestring support me this without any conversion which i had to do it in plan string datatype

Comment: @Pravin You have 2 choices here: passing `TimeSpan` as formatted JSON string or passing JSON object then manipulate output string in JS (using `lectureStartTime.Hours` & `lectureStartTime.Minutes` respectively). But I'm confused how to set AM/PM string depending from `Hours` property (which possibly turns into 24 hour format).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  Is there any datatype better than timespan which give me 10:00 AM formating both in javascript and mvc page also

Comment: `(new Date(item.lectureStartTime.TotalMilliseconds)).toLocaleTimeString()`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis its working but see difference for this "08:00 AM - 08:25 AM" it showing  like 1:30:00 PM - 1:55:00 PM

Comment: convert to JSON (via serialization) and then catch in response.data in javascript.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ? If you did, can you answer your own question and mark it as "solved" so it doesn't stay at the top of the list ? Or tag someone's answer if they helped.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be doing this instead ?

```
var row = "";
var time = item.lectureStartTime.Hours + " : " + item.lectureStartTime.Minutes + " : " + item.lectureStartTime.Seconds;
  jQuery.each(response.content, function (index, item) {
     row += "<tr ><td>" + time  + " </td> </tr>";
       });
  $("#tbldialogfacultyclash").html(row);
```

Since lectureStartTime is a complex object you will have to construct the string yourself.

You could also add a property like this in your Model

```
public string lectureStartTimeStr => $"{lectureStartTime.Hours} : {lectureStartTime.Hours} : {lectureStartTime.Minutes}";
```

edit: after reading the comments I changed my approach, I think that what you are looking for would be something like this (if you chose to use the property in a ViewModel)

```
public string lectureStartTimeStr => $"{lectureStartTime:hh:mm:ss tt}";
```

this way your Javascript can simply be

```
var row = "";
jQuery.each(response.content, function (index, item) {
    row += "<tr ><td>" + item.lectureStartTimeStr + " </td> </tr>";
});
$("#tbldialogfacultyclash").html(row);
```